# Reliable UDP in java

Tags: java

I am working on my assignment to make UDP reliable using java. How can i add Timeout and re-transmission to handle data-grams that are discarded and add Sequence numbers so the client can verify that a reply is for the appropriate request ??

this is client code

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class EchoClient {
// UDP port to which service is bound
    public static final int SERVICE_PORT = 7;


// Max size of packet
public static final int BUFSIZE = 256;
public static void main(String args[]){
                 if (args.length != 1)
                 {
                         System.err.println ("Syntax - java EchoClient hostname");
                         return;
                  }
String hostname = args[0];
// Get an InetAddress for the specified hostname
    InetAddress addr = null;
        try
        {
            // Resolve the hostname to an InetAddr
            addr = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException uhe)
        {
            System.err.println ("Unable to resolve host");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            // Bind to any free port
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();

            // Set a timeout value of two seconds
            socket.setSoTimeout (2 * 1000);

            for (int i = 1 ; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                // Copy some data to our packet
                String message = "Packet number " + i ;
                char[] cArray = message.toCharArray();                  
                byte[] sendbuf = new byte[cArray.length];
                for (int offset = 0; offset < cArray.length ; offset++)
                {
                    sendbuf[offset] = (byte) cArray[offset];
                }

                // Create a packet to send to the UDP server
                DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendbuf, cArray.length, addr, SERVICE_PORT);

                System.out.println ("Sending packet to " + hostname);

                // Send the packet
                socket.send (sendPacket);

                System.out.print ("Waiting for packet.... ");

                // Create a small packet for receiving UDP packets
                byte[] recbuf = new byte[BUFSIZE];
                DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(recbuf, BUFSIZE);

                // Declare a timeout flag
                boolean timeout = false;

                // Catch any InterruptedIOException that is thrown
                // while waiting to receive a UDP packet
                try
                {
                    socket.receive (receivePacket);
                }
                catch (InterruptedIOException ioe)
                {
                    timeout = true;
                }

                if (!timeout)
                {
                    System.out.println ("packet received!");
                    System.out.println ("Details : " + receivePacket.getAddress() );

                    // Obtain a byte input stream to read the UDP packet
                    ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream (
                      receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength() );

                    // Connect a reader for easier access
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader ( 
                      new InputStreamReader ( bin ) );

                    // Loop indefinitely
                    for (;;)
                    {
                        String line = reader.readLine();

                        // Check for end of data
                        if (line == null)
                            break;
                        else
                            System.out.println (line);
                    }               
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println ("packet lost!");
                }

                // Sleep for a second, to allow user to see packet
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            System.err.println ("Socket error " + ioe);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: UDP was set up specifically to be unreliable. On the other hand, TCP is built to be reliable. So if you want reliable, you should use TCP

Comment: @ControlAltDel that is not totally true. People often take advantage of the performance gain in UDP by creating their own service on top of it.

Comment: that is fine but we can add some  features to client to make it reliable like check-sum or sequence number and Timeout

Comment: @flkes I think ControlAltDel is correct, people do create protocol like UDP, but UDP itself is designed to be unreliable. UDP does not have option header, meaning there is not room to add sequence number, buffer and window support on client and server side, and those three headers are the main factors to make TCP reliable.

Comment: @M.N.N, I don't think you can add them, because UDP has no room for you to add extra headers. You can add buffers or create windows on two sides, but you can only improve the reliability to certain degree.

Comment: @Bond I'm not arguing the characteristics of raw UDP; my comment was more directed at saying "if you want reliable, you should use TCP". You can use a transport layer service such as TCP or UDP to create an application service which fits your needs. Much like how TCP and UDP use the network layer (which has its own properties, formats and reliability guarantees) to realize higher level services.

Comment: we cant use TCP the doctor ask us to make UDP reliable @ControlAltDel

Comment: UDB characteristics are dropped packets, out-of-order reception of packets and such. This means you need to build some intelligence in protocol and data.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is adding import TCP headers like sequence number, windows into the UDP message body to make it more like TCP. Here is the a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22889574/3077801) that might help you.